# Disable AutoCommit on remote branch while working on Local Branch in STS (Eclipse GIT)

Tags: git, git-branch, spring-tool-suite, autocommit

I created local branch **"local1"** referencing remote branch **"remote1"**. I am using STS for the development which has this git integrated within. So, i pretty much can see all the branches (local and remote both) in STS git. Once I make any changes into one of the files in **local1** branch, all the changes gets reflected in **remote1** branch in eclipse git. 
But, when i manually got to remote ripo, i can see no changes that i have currently made in **local1**.

**So, why is my git responding so wierd. I just want to avoid auto sync/commit to remote1 branch while i work on local1 branch. Is there any auto commit disable/enable option in STS ?**

Answer (score 0):

So when you get the remote it doesn't have the changes which you think were auto committed.

That implies that the changes are not auto committed.

I do not use STS, but my advice would be to:
a) Check if what you are seeing is the result of an IDE configuration setting.
b) Find out what the meaning is of what you are seeing in the context of the IDE, maybe you are coming to conclusions based on not fully understanding what is shown to you.

Comment: Alwyn, My question is, i can see changes of my local edit (in local branch) and are reflected into the remote branch (while i go switch branch  to remote1 branch in STS/Eclipse git. ) but actually they are not reflected into remote1 branch in actual repo (remote). Ya, I have seen some sort of setting regarding git preferences in Windows > Preferences > git . But I am not sure about which checkbox inside the preference to enable or disable ? Did you get my question ?

Comment: Bharat, I looked at the settings and it didn't look as if there is something that could cause this.

Comment: Since I am not familiar with using git in eclipse.  What do you mean when you say "I go switch branch to remote1 branch".  I have installed STS so you can give instructions I can follow to reproduce.

Comment: Alwyn, I am having lots of branches in remote (say, remoteBranch1, remoteBranch2, remoteBranch3). I do have several branches in my local as well (say, localBranch1, localBranch2, localBranch3). Suppose, for now I am pulling from remoteBranch1 into my localBranch1.   So, now i do have updated code from remoteBranch1 into my localBranch1. But, once i edit or make some changes in my localBranch1 all the changes in remoteBranch1(in STS, ***without any commits). And I have not made any changes/settings for git in STS.

Comment: When I make a change in my local branch in STS without committing then the only changes I see are the following:

Comment: - In synchronize tab I see there are outgoing changes.
- In git staging tab I see there are uncommitted changes.